# How do I implement coroutines on WebAssembly?

Tags: implementation, compilers, coroutines, webassembly

I am building a compiler targeting WebAssembly for a language that makes heavy use of first-class coroutines. WASM doesn't have native coroutine support (yet), so I have to emulate it. Given the native tools that WebAssembly *does* provide, what is the most suitable approach to implementing them?

These are primarily within-language coroutines, but calls out to platform functionality will occur within them occasionally. Coroutines are currently stackless but ubiquitous. I am primarily interested in browser-based execution, but ideally it would work on [other WASM environments as well](https://webassembly.org/roadmap/).

Comment: Is this in particular about Simultaneous Co-routines aka threads, or Asymmetric Co-routines like [Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/9.1.html)?

Comment: @ATaco Asymmetric.

Comment: Cooperative stackless coroutines are State Machines (Automata) in disguise, aren't they? Thus you'll need to transform them into explicit SMs in a usual way (like Async in C# or Rust or pretty much everywhere), and add a shim to switch from one machine to another on top of that. At least that's how I understand your question...

Comment: @AlexChichigin State machines could form the basis of an answer. Any means of implementing these in WebAssembly is in scope.

Comment: @MichaelHomer pretty much the only way you **can't** implement a state machine in Wasm is via mutual tail-recursive functions. Not until tail calls proposal stabilizes. Every other approach from any other language should work. Modulo manual implementation of OOP and alike. A [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata-based_programming) has a number of examples.

Comment: @AlexChichigin You can post an answer below.

Comment: @MichaelHomer that would answer a different question: "how do I implement state machines on WebAssembly?"

Comment: @AlexChichigin Regardless, answers go in the answer box below, not in the comments, and definitely not in the comments of questions you don't think they answer.

Comment: It is about javascript, but I expect it will apply as well to wasm—see this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.02974

Answer (score 3):

## For Symmetrically, Not Natively, However...

Web Assembly does not provide a native solution to multiple threads, meaning each solution will have to be platform specific.

You will need to import a function that handles messaging on the target platform for the purpose of spawning and communicating between threads, this can be handled in Javascript via [Web-Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Exact implementation will of course depend on the language details.